# MySQL Update multiple tables query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update two tables in MySQL with one query, and am running into an error. I've looked at similar situations and resolutions, but can't seem to translate them to my specific query/situation as I am continuing to get the same error. My goal seems like there is an obvious solution I am missing. My Query is as follows:

```
UPDATE table_pr, table_pu
INNER JOIN table_pu ON table_pr.id = table_pu.pr_id
SET table_pr.cpr2 = table_pu.cpr2_id, table_pu.cpr_updated = '1'
WHERE table_pu.cpr2_date < CURRENT_DATE()
```

When I run the Update, I get *Not unique table/alias: 'table_pu'* returned. I prefer to not use aliases in this, but I've also tried to set unique aliases for the tables with the same result. If my approach should be modified, my ultimate goal is to have `table_pr.cpr2` set to `table_pu.cpr2_id` based on `WHERE table_pu.cpr2_date < CURRENT_DATE()` and if the update is run, to also set `table_pu.cpr_updated = '1'`

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `UPDATE table_pr INNER JOIN table_pu ON` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the second table reference in the UPDATE statement resolved the issue.